# Android: Updating textview at a some specific interval of time

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to update the textview at every certain time, but it only updates the first and then it force closes, here is the code:

```
try {
           timer = new Timer();
           timerTask = new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
             //Download file here and refresh
                  updateRecSMSCount(count);
              }
           };
        timer.schedule(timerTask,0, 3000);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){

        }
void updateRecSMSCount(Integer count)
{
    TextView numRecSMS=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.numRecSMS);
    numRecSMS.setText(count.toString());

}
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the UI from other thread than the thread that created the UI. The timer task runs in different thread. You can find solutions here: [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

The most simple repair is:

```
void updateRecSMSCount(Integer count)
{
    final TextView numRecSMS=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.numRecSMS);

    numRecSMS.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            numRecSMS.setText(count.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I looked at the Updating UI from timer and the first example did not work and the other example is onClickListener, but I was to update it would user clicking anything. 

The example you gave works only once and then it does not update, it would be great if you could help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: Actually never mind, it is actually working. I was not initializing my counter variable. Thank You very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the contents of the view from another thread. You need to look at the `Handler`-class. See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).